# How can I create a new layer from the current selection using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

Is it possible to create a duplicate layer, only displaying the selection from the layer you are duplicating in QuantumGIS?
Similar to ArcGIS -> Create Layer from Selected Features.

I looked at "How to duplicate a layer"

```
iface = qgis.utils.iface
vl = iface.activeLayer()
iface.addVectorLayer( vl.source(), vl.name(), vl.providerType() )
```

but can't see how to duplicate only the selected features?

Answer (score 8):

You can retrieve the selected features with

```
vl = iface.activeLayer()
selectedFeatures = vl.selectedFeatures()
```

You then need to add a new vector layer.
If you want your duplicate layer only in memory (i.e. not persistent) use a memory layer (see the [pyqgis cookbook](http://qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/vector.html#memory-provider))
If you want your layer to be persistent, refer to the section about [writing vector layers](http://qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/vector.html#writing-vector-layers).

Use then the [QgsVectorFileWriter.addFeature](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#abb63125ba95ea627f29ea9663fb8b4c2) or [QgsVectorLayer.addFeatures](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a9936fbfbd69efc6583062e16c6c219ed) method on the retrieved layer / layerwriter to add the features.

In case you have really many features, it might be prudent to use [selectedFeaturesIds()](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a33968fa939503a9e3873c88e5f0ea439) and then query and iterate over these to not have to copy all the features into the memory.

Comment: You can also use "save selection as". First you select the feature(s),then select the layer, right click and choose save selection as. Here you can define the type of file, shape for instance. Works like data export data /selected features in ArcMap

Comment: Good point. It's a bit unclear from the question, if python is involved or a UI only solution is looked for.

Comment: There is a little typo in the code: it should say activeLayer, not acitveLayer. Unfortunately I cannot edit just one character.