# Why does my PyQGIS code for saving selected features result in altered geometries?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

In a plugin I want to save the selected features in a new shapefile. I search and I try  ([How can I create a new layer from the currrent selection?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/64153) to create a new layer and write the selected fields and features in that:

```
    vl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "temporary_points", "memory")
    pr = vl.dataProvider()

    # add geometry and fields
    pr.addAttributes(fields)
    pr.addFeatures(features)
```

But this result is not what I wanted. I get this:
[image]

In this image, the selected polygon is yellow and the pink polygon is the saved one as another shapefile. So the geometry is not completely correct and I need the perfect copy of the original.

Anyone knows how to get it?

---

I can use the algorithm from Processing Toolbox, "Save selected features".

Comment: How about the "Save as"  option?? You can select your features and then right click, you choose Save as>-Save only selected features.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I want in Python code.

Comment: I get it. Ii can use the algorithm in processing toolbox, "Save selected features". Thanks anyway. I will edit the question.

Comment: Did you search on GIS SE ? ([How can I create a new layer from the currrent selection?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/64153), ...)

Comment: yes, that's what I did in the first place and get the result presented in image.

Answer (score 1):

You can save selected features from your active layer into a Shapefile simply calling `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat` and passing the `onlySelected` parameter as `True`:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
res = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat( layer,
                                               '/tmp/selectedFeatures.shp',
                                               'System',
                                               None, #crs
                                               'ESRI Shapefile',
                                               True #onlySelected
                                             )
if res != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
    print 'Error number:', res
else:
    print "Done!"
```

The resulting layer will contain all fields from source layer.